# Disable Travis-CI for pull requests

Tags: travis-ci

I have a project that uses Travis-CI to build and `rsync` a static website. I use the following to ensure that this only occurs in `master`.

```
branches:
  only:
    - master
```

However, when someone makes a pull request on the repository, Travis-CI prospectively merges that branch into master and does the build and `rsync`, meaning that anyone could replace the contents of my website with anything by submitting a pull request.

**Is there a way to prevent Travis-CI from attempting to build pull requests?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't you disable PULL request builds? At least, at the time of this writing, I see that as a choice on a per repo setting:

[image: build pull requests]

Comment: This wasn't the case when I originally made this question. Now, this answer is definitely the recommended way to go!

Answer (score 11):

You can find out if Travis is checking a pull request by checking the environment variable `TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST`. It contains:

> The pull request number if the current job is a pull request, "false" if it's not a pull request.

See also [the docs](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/ci-environment/).

You can change your command to check this and only build on non-pull requests with

```
if [[ $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST == 'false' ]]; then your-command; fi
```

To avoid the scenario described by @ruslo, you can (and should!) use [encrypted environment variables](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/encryption-keys/) for building the rsync connection. These are not available with pull requests (at least with those that come from a fork), so that everything's safe here:

> Please note that secure env variables are not available for pull requests from forks. This is done due to the security risk of exposing such information in submitted code. Everyone can submit a pull request and if an unencrypted variable is available there, it could be easily displayed.

(The reasons stated in the docs are different, but the mechanism would work here as well.)

Comment: You're right @ruslo, but if security was a big concern I wouldn't let Travis-CI do this at all ;) This asnwer is great for my purposes!

Comment: Good point; we do use encrypted environment variables, but in this case it was a pull request within the same repository, rather than a fork. But yes, people with push/pull access won't be doing anything malicious with the PRs so we should be safe on all fronts.